# What is the `text encoding` of source swift files on Xcode

Tags: xcode, encoding, xcode11

I was trying to copy-paste a UTF-8 string with Japanese characters and saved it assigned to a variable on swift. When I was trying to parse that variable with json string I see encoding issues in the exception.

Anyways I solved it by putting the content in an external file and loading it from bundle of course the encoding was same as before which is `.utf8` and it worked.

I later read from the `File Inspector` that `Swift` file where the `Text Encoding` is mentioned as `No Explicit Encoding`.

Can someone point to documentation which says what is the `Text Encoding` by default when any source files are added to Xcode 11 onwards. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in Xcode Preferences on Text Editing pane. Please look my attached.

[image]